# AWS Athena: Get part of the String after last delimiter

Tags: presto, amazon-athena

I have the this table in AWS Athena

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     URL                                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| stag.v1.abc.in/beauty/hair/go-abc-girl-a57-20200001?ref=home_feed_1        |
| stag.v1.abc.in/                                                            |
| stag.v1.abc.ph/eatdrink/cheap/76027/dairy-free-upsize-a1046-20190515?ref=ar|              
| stag.v1.abc.in/beauty/hair/go-abc-girl-a57-20200003?ref=home_feed_1        |        
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to extract the part (id) of the string from columns between two delimiters(after last '-'  and before '?')
I should get

```
+------------------------+
|     ID                 |
+------------------------+
| 20200001               |
| -                      |
| 20190515               |              
| 20200003               |        
+------------------------+
```

I tried SUBSTRING_INDEX() But athena does not support it.Could anyone help me out in this. Thanks in advance

Comment: For working with URLs, check out URL functions: https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/url.html (they were available in Presto .172 too, the version which Athena is based on.) You would call [`url_extract_path`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/url.html#url_extract_path) and then perhaps [`regexp_extract`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract).

Comment: That worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`url_extract_path`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/url.html#url_extract_path) + [`regexp_extract`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_extract)

```
select regexp_extract(url_extract_path(url),'([^-]*)$') from "tableabc" 
limit 5;
```